# I get the following error for all my android projects after updating android sdk and adt plugin for eclipse

Tags: android

Following is a screenshot of the error.

[image: Screenshot.]

[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vWgT.png) for full size.

Comment: Could you post your manifest file please?

Comment: You must download new android sdk and adt plugins and use that.

Comment: Following is android manifest.xml :

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/241tpqs/6   ::::::::::: Manifest url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the manifest.

```
<manifest>
      .....
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="lowest_sdk_supported" />
</manifest>
```

Its one of the warnings that says "Application does not specify an API level requirement.